# React Native app crashes on Pixel devices

Tags: android, react-native

The application builds without any issues but when it is installed on the real Pixel devices it crashed on start.

From the Google Play console, I see the error in pre-launch reports with this stack trace:

```
Signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Pointer tag for 0x79a03e8170 was truncated.'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000594c  x2  0000000000000006  x3  00000078fd5da880
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  0000000000000020
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  0000007c142be7c0  x10 ffffff80fffffbdf  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000018  x13 0000000000000003  x14 0000000000000065  x15 00000078fd5da2b2
    x16 0000007c14356c80  x17 0000007c14338320  x18 00000078fd0fe000  x19 00000000000058f2
    x20 000000000000594c  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 00000078fd5da9c0  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 0000000000000099  x25 00000000000000a5  x26 00000079013521e2  x27 0000007901354010
    x28 0000007901354000  x29 00000078fd5da900
    lr  0000007c142ec148  sp  00000078fd5da860  pc  0000007c142ec178  pst 0000000000001000
```

I can see the same issue using the logcat with the connected real device to the laptop. On the emulator, it is not reproducible.

Before this error, it was another one with `okhttp3` but it was fixed by adding the following code to the `android/build/build.gradle`:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2")
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.2")
```

React Native version is: `"react-native": "0.63.3"`

Any idea what this might be related to?